# Does hadoop Behave differently in local and distributed mode for static variables

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Suppose I am having a static variables assigned to a class variables in my mapper, the value of the static variable depends upon the job, hence it is same of a set of input splits being executed in a job tracker node for that Job and hence I can assign the Job Specific Variables directly as static Variables in my Mapper (The JVM running in the Job Tracker Node).

For Some Different Job,  these values will change as it is a different Job and have different Class Path Variables for its own Job, but I believe it will not impact the former mentioned job as they are running in different JVMs(Jobtracker).

Now If i try this in the local mode, the above Different Job will be runnig inthe same JVM, hence when this Diferent Job will try to overrire the Job Specific Class Variables which my formar Job had set, it will cause a problem for my former Job.

So can we say that the behavior of same code in Local and Distributed mode in not same always.

The Class Variables I am setting is nothing but some resource level and distributed cache values.

I know the use case is not good, but just wanted to know if this is what will happen when it comes to static variables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of static variables is not encouraged for the same reason you mentioned. The behavior is surely different based on the mode in which Hadoop is running. if the static is just a resource name and you are just reading it, the usage is fine. But if trying to modify, it will impact in standalone mode. Also, as you know, the standalone and psuedo is just for beginners and learning.  Usecases should not dictate our learning :)  Happy learning.

Comment: So the approach is , everything that works in distributed mode works in local mode, but everything in local mode does not behave the same in distributed mode